# BigInteger(long) has private access in BigInteger

Tags: java, private, biginteger

I am trying to store a big calculation in a BigInteger instance. I tried this :

```
BigInteger answer=new BigInteger(2+3);
```

and got the following error :

```
temp.java:17: error: BigInteger(long) has private access in BigInteger
                        BigInteger answer=new BigInteger(2+3);
                                          ^
1 error
```

I know that instead of "2+3" there should be a string value. But i don't know how to satisfy that condition(assuming that i don't how much 2+3 is). Please tell me how to assign a calculated value to BigInteger object(assign 2+3 to BigInteger answer).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186277/why-is-there-bigintegerstring-but-no-bigintegerlong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to perform the arithmetic using `BigInteger`, you should create a `BigInteger` for each value and then use `BigInteger.add`. However, you *don't* need to use strings to do that. You may want to if your input is already a string and it might be long, but if you've already got a `long`, you can use [`BigInteger.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-). For example:

```
BigInteger answer = BigInteger.valueOf(2).add(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
```

I certainly wouldn't convert a `long` into a `String` just to then pass it into the `BigInteger` constructor.

Comment: So, why should the OP do the above rather than `BigInteger.valueOf(2+3)`?

Comment: @HotLicks: It depends on what their *real* situation is. Perhaps they're actually taking in strings as inputs. Or even if they're taking in `long` values as inputs, they may well not want the result to overflow - for example, `Long.MAX_VALUE + Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: getting cannot find BigInteger.valueOf error

Comment: @RohanDevaki: Without more information, I can't really help. Perhaps you don't have an import for it?

Comment: I have, it is working now, thanks, but i getting null value, when i am returning to a function, how do i print the value of it.

Comment: @RohanDevaki: Please don't use a question from nearly 8 years ago to try to get semi-interactive debugging help. Post a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You could just use BigInteger's `add(...)` method:

```
BigInteger answer = new BigInteger("2").add(new BigInteger("3"));
```

No worries about overflow with this solution.