# Why is there BigInteger(String) but no BigInteger(long)?

Tags: java, biginteger, factory-pattern

In Java, to convert a String to BigInteger you use the constructor `new BigInteger(String)` but to convert an int/long you use the factory function `BigInteger.valueof(long)`, why is that?

Comment: That is just how they designed it when they built it.  You would have to ask whoever created BigInteger that question.

Comment: Typically the implementation caches common values like positive integers close to 0.

Comment: @JakeCobb - exactly - in this case, it caches values between -16 and 16.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There actually *is* a `BigInteger(long)` constructor, but it's private. The javadoc on the factory method provides info on why:

> This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long)
>   constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used
>   BigIntegers.

Answer (score 21):

@Morad you can find the answer in the docs: [JavaDoc of BigInteger.valueOf(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29):

> This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long)
>   constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used
>   BigIntegers.

**Explained**: `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` does exactly what you would expect from the  `BigInteger(long)` constructor, and it is (or should be) **more efficient at it**.